# php nl2br vice versa issues

Tags: php, nl2br

i currently i am using textarea where user can submit their input. I am using php `nl2br` to convert any new line into `<br>` as follow:

```
$review_desc = nl2br($this->_getParam('comment'));
```

but now i have issues when user edit their text as i am getting content as follow:

```
test1<br />
test2<br />
test3<br />
test4<br />
```

where it adds new `<br/>` at the end on line when user edit their content in textarea.How can i prevent this? Also for suggestion is there any other replacement to textarea in form where it can detect hyperlink etc ? Thanks

Comment: Are you HTML-escaping the content *afterwards*?

Comment: @deceze u mean escaping before rendering to users to edit again?

Comment: I mean something like `<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars(nl2br($text)); ?></textarea>`

Comment: @deceze haven't tried, let me work it out. Thanks

Comment: @deceze Totally OT, but why aren't you considering a mod job here? I've seen you very active for PHP tagged questions

Comment: @zlippr No, that's exactly what you're *not* supposed to do.

Comment: @asprin Meh. I'm already wasting enough time here as it is... ;-)

Comment: @deceze That's exactly the point. You're spending your time on SO anyhow...why not do it in a different role?

Comment: @deceze not work well, adding htmlspecialchars(nl2br($this->_getParam('comment'))); when saving the text resulting no new line, out put the result also create double break line

Comment: @asprin As a practical problem, I don't have the Convention badge, so I'm officially not eligible... :)

Comment: @zlippr As I said, that's exactly what you're ***not*** supposed to do. What exactly *are* you doing?

Comment: @deceze saving text from textarea when user submit a form.

Comment: OMG, what happen i still cant get solutions for this problems??

Answer (score 0):

You can store the content of the textarea in the database as it was provided by the user; so without calling nl2br.

Then only call nl2br, once you retrieved the same text from the database and want to print to the webpage.

When you want the user to edit it again in the textarea, retrieve the current content from the database and do not call nl2br this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep text with "\n", you can simply insert text in textarea, but if you keep text with `<br />`, before inserting text in textarea, you should replace `<br />` on "\n", for example `$text = str_replace("<br />","\n",$text);` or try something from this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php, there many functions in comments for replacing `<br />` on \n